# ValueError: could not convert string to float: med

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am writing a very simple script. All I have to do is read data using panda and then train a decision tree on data. Data that I am using is:

```
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data
```

And following is my script

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
balance_data=pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data",
                           sep= ',', header= None)
#print "Dataset:: "

#df1.head()

X = balance_data.values[:, 0:5]
Y = balance_data.values[:,6]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 100)
clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", random_state = 100,
                               max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)

clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

From the error I am guessing that it couldn't convert "med" attribute value to float. And by looking at the data my random guess is that low has a space before it and med doesn't. That is why it is getting confused. But I am not sure of it. Please tell what could be wrong with it. 
PS: error is occurring at the last line and here is the traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-b495e5f26174> in <module>()
     18                                max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)
     19 X_train[X_train != '']
---> 20 clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)

/home/fatima/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    788             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    789             check_input=check_input,
--> 790             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    791         return self
    792 

/home/fatima/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    114         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    115         if check_input:
--> 116             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    117             y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    118             if issparse(X):

/home/fatima/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    400                                       force_all_finite)
    401     else:
--> 402         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    403 
    404         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: med
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dataset looks like this:

```
       0      1  2  3      4     5      6
0  vhigh  vhigh  2  2  small   low  unacc
1  vhigh  vhigh  2  2  small   med  unacc
2  vhigh  vhigh  2  2  small  high  unacc
3  vhigh  vhigh  2  2    med   low  unacc
4  vhigh  vhigh  2  2    med   med  unacc
```

Where the data types (dtypes) are all objects. However, machine learning algorithms can only learn from numbers (int, float, doubles .. ) thus, you need to encode your data before you use it for training.

There are several ways to encode your data, one way is to use `label encoding`, to do that, add the following lines to your code just after loading the dataset:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
balance_data = balance_data.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

Now the data in `balance_data` looks like this:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  3  3  0  0  2  1  2
1  3  3  0  0  2  2  2
2  3  3  0  0  2  0  2
3  3  3  0  0  1  1  2
4  3  3  0  0  1  2  2
```

where all data types are int.

In general, you need to perform some data preprocessing before training/fitting your model. For that, I recommend that you go through some tutorial to understand the process. For instance, check this:

- [practical-guide-data-preprocessing-python-scikit-learn](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/07/practical-guide-data-preprocessing-python-scikit-learn/)

---

Here's the **overall code** with the fix:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
balance_data=pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data",
                           sep= ',', header= None)
#print "Dataset:: "

#df1.head()

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
balance_data = balance_data.apply(le.fit_transform)

X = balance_data.values[:, 0:5]
Y = balance_data.values[:,6]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 100)
clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", random_state = 100,
                               max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)

clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch :) I was trying to use LabelEncoder() but didn't know how to use it

Comment: @HannahMontanna you are welcome :), look up the tutorial I linked to, to gain some experience around data preprocessing..

Comment: Why decision tree classifier needs to have labelencoded the data variables. Ain't it supposed to work with categorical variables??

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the file you are trying to process, and I found this is the data:

```
vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,med,unacc
vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,high,unacc
vhigh,vhigh,2,2,med,low,unacc
vhigh,vhigh,2,2,med,med,unacc
vhigh,vhigh,2,2,med,high,unacc
```

So when you ask for train the model, internally is trying to convert your vector into numbers, but founds strings values (as "small", "med", "high", etc) wich are not parseables to a number.

A good start could be normalize your categorical values into onehot encoding. Check it here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html